# Update ERROR Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE User SET username='basta2',password=sha2('basta',512), role='User' disabled=0 WHERE username='basta';
```

This query should be correct in my opinion, but gives me this error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'disabled=0 WHERE username='basta'' at line 1

What is wrong here?

Comment: missing `,` after `role = 'User'`

Comment: Damn tiredness, cheers man

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @vkp, the issue is a missing `,`. Use this:

```
UPDATE User SET username='basta2',password=sha2('basta',512), role='User', disabled=0 WHERE username='basta';
```